# How to display more than one page with PageView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an app that use *PageView* and I want to make it responsive – such that on a tablet, it shows 3 pages and with a smartphone, it shows only one:

[image]

How can I change the number of pages shown in a PageView?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can control how many pages are displayed in a *PageView* through a *PageController*

```
var controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 1 / 3);
```

Then pass it to your *PageView*:

```
PageView(
  controller: controller,
  ...
),
```

Comment: This seems to only work well with viewport 1/3 but not with 1/2 because it shows one page in the center and half a page to the left and another half to the right. Is there a way to show 2 whole pages next to each other?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use LayoutBuilder to check the max width and then you can set the `PageController(viewportFraction: );` accordingly.

Here is an example:

```
  PageController pageController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constrains) {
        if (constrains.maxWidth < 600) {
          pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 1.0);
        } else {
          pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.3);
        }
        return PageView.builder(
          controller: pageController,
          itemCount: places.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            // return your view for pageview
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PageView.builder(
        controller: PageController(
          viewportFraction: 0.8,
        ),
        padEnds: false,
        itemCount: ...,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ...;
        },
      );
```

is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Some addition to accepted answer: if you wand to display two or other even number of pages use `padEnds: false`

```
          PageView.builder(
            controller: PageController(
              viewportFraction: 1/2,
            ),
            padEnds: false,
            itemCount: ...,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ...;
            },
          );
```